# labels as values in clang

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, clang, goto

I'm trying to implement "labels as values" (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) in a c program using clang 3.7 in Visual Studio 2015.

As a toy example I had the following code which causes the compiler to crash (internal error "fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'c:\agent\build\cache\git\vctools\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 246)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.").

```
const void *array_jump[] = {&&S1,&&S2,&&S3,&&S3,&&S4};  

S1:
    goto *array_jump[3];
S2:
    return 2;
S3:
    return 3;
S4:
    return 4;
```

If I move the array declaration to after all of the labels it works, until I include the array_jump variable in any of the statements.

```
S1:
    //comment out and add "return 1;" and it will compile fine
    goto *array_jump[3];
S2:
    return 2;
S3:
    return 3;
S4:
    return 4;

const void *array_jump[] = {&&S1,&&S2,&&S3,&&S3,&&S4};
```

Can anyone provide an example like the one above that should work? Is this a problem with clang or with the "codegen" aspect for Visual Studio?

I think this bug is relevant but I'm not sure:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2103400/crash-in-clang-c2-with-address-of-label-extension

Comment: This is terrible coding style. Why don't you use a `switch` or a function table. If you really want such code, you should `goto` 70ies/80ies BASIC.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite there's no way to make that judgment based on the code given, unless you just think `goto` is sinful.  This is at least as clear as a `switch`, clearer than an array of FPs, and (which is likely the point) significantly faster than either.  The labels-as-values extension exists because, in particular, you can't write a direct threaded interpreter in C without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The examples you build should work, I've just verified it using `Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)`.

The mentioned bug reports seem to report this very same issue, until it's fixed, you can't do anything aside from trying to not use the extension.

While `GNU C` has some great extensions, if you want to write portable [c](/questions/tagged/c) code, try to avoid using any `GNU C` extension.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The hope was that with using clang in Visual Studio I would be able to get portable code.

Comment: @Jimbo could use Clang with LLVM instead of C2 as backend. That seems to work (I've used the r265934 build from [here](http://llvm.org/builds/) but any stable version probably also works).

Comment: @cremno That worked great, thanks!!! I had no idea that clang was working with C2 (or what C2 was). The whole clang vs llvm thing (i.e. that these are different) makes sense now.

Comment: @Jimbo `clang` is just a compiler frontend. `LLVM` is the compiler backend.

Answer (score -2):

What you've linked to is a gnu-specific extension to the language.  If you're not using a gnu compiler (I don't believe clang is), then it won't necessarily work.  The documentation says to check for definition of the `__GNUC__` name in the processor.  Try adding this...

```
#ifndef __GNUC__
#error Not a GNU compiler, does not include GNU specific extensions
#endif
```

Comment: `clang` does have most of the GNU extensions, and also defines the `__GNUC__` macro.

Comment: I would say the bug link in the original post answers the question, then.  It's a known bug, and until the bug is addressed, it's not going to work.

Comment: Yes, but still, your answer is wrong. `clang` does define `__GNUC__` and has the mentioned extension.